Capture the Selected Radio Button Value between two files in wordpress theme
 $html_output .= '<div class="form-group">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="driver_type" value="society" checked required> Society</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label><input type="radio" name="driver_type" value="entrepreneur"> Entrepreneur</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label><input type="radio" name="driver_type" value="other"> Other</label>
                </div>';

i tried to do it with script but didn't work
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var driverTypeRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="driver_type"]');

        driverTypeRadios.forEach(function(radio) {
            radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
                if (this.checked) {
                    var myvalue = this.value;
                    console.log('Selected Driver Type:', myvalue);

                    // Send myvalue to PHP via AJAX
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
                            // Success - do something if needed
                            console.log('Response:', xhr.responseText);
                        } else {
                            // Error - handle errors if needed
                            console.error('Request failed:', xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.onerror = function() {
                        // Handle network errors
                        console.error('Network error occurred');
                    };
                    xhr.send('action=handle_selected_driver_type&myvalue=' + encodeURIComponent(myvalue));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


what doesn't work ? edit your question to show the debug you made.
